# Python script throwing error except when in debug mode, but works fine on another system

Tags: python, debugging, visual-studio-code

As aforementioned in the title, this script works perfectly fine on my desktop, and all of the required packages are installed on my laptop, though for some reason its throwing this error. It doesn't have any issue in debugger mode, but it will not work when just trying to run this normally in VSCode

```
import tkinter as tk
import requests


#Functions

def usd_to_yuan():
    yuan = (float(conversion.get("1.0", "end-1c")) * 6.47)
    btn_load.config(text=f"The conversion is roughly {yuan} yuan")

def yuan_to_usd():
    dollars = (float(conversion.get("1.0","end-1c")) * 0.15)
    btn_load2.config(text=f"The conversion is roughly {dollars} usd")


#Format Window

window = tk.Tk()
window.geometry("800x600")
window.title("Currency Conversion")
window.config(padx=5,pady=5,background="#E1C1F5")

title_label = tk.Label(window, text = "Currency Conversion")
title_label.config(font=("Arial",16))
title_label.pack(padx=5,pady=5)

btn_load = tk.Button(window,text="Convert to CNY", command=usd_to_yuan)
btn_load.config(font=("Arial",20))
btn_load.pack(padx=10,pady=10)

btn_load2 = tk.Button(window,text="Convert to USD", command=yuan_to_usd)
btn_load2.config(font=("Arial",20))
btn_load2.pack(padx=10,pady=10)

conversion = tk.Text(window,height=1,width=20)
conversion.config(font=("Arial",10))
conversion.pack(padx=5,pady=5)

window.mainloop()
```

Screenshot of the error its throwing

[image: Screenshot of the error its throwing]

Comment: I copied your code and ran it on my machine - the only issue I had was that for some reason I can't get Python to recognize the `requests` module, even though it says it is installed. But the code you posted doesn't use that module anyway. So the code worked fine for me. Can you copy the entire error message instead of just a part of it?

Comment: "[Running] python -u "/Users/xiaoan/Desktop/Programming/Python/CurrencyConverter.py"
  File "/Users/xiaoan/Desktop/Programming/Python/CurrencyConverter.py", line 9
    btn_load.config(text=f"The conversion is roughly {yuan} yuan")
                                                                ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

[Done] exited with code=1 in 0.099 seconds
" This is the entire terminal output upon running the script, and as far as the requests go, I believe its being called in my .get's

Comment: What version of Python are you using? f-Strings were introduced in Python 3.6, I would guess your version is older than that. And you are not using the `requests` module in your `conversion.get()` call, this is calling the object `conversion` which is defined as a `tk.Text` object, so it is calling the `get()` function of that object.

Comment: Your code works well on my machine, can you try running it in integrated Terminal, does the error still exists?

Comment: What is the reason of the first `(` and last `)` in `yuan = (float(conversion.get("1.0", "end-1c")) * 6.47)`, Bad UI practice to change the button text to show output, what if you want a second conversion what button to press, code runs fine for me too